# Como agregar autentificacion SMTP a este codigo php?

Tags: php

Necesito agregar a este codigo php validación smtp de gmail o de mi propio dominio, desconozco como hacerlo ya que este formulario lo conseguí en la red y estoy empezando a familiarizarme con el lenguaje php. Gracias!

```
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "email title";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function*/
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Favor de ingresar su nombre");
$company = check_input($_POST['company']);
$telephone = check_input($_POST['telephone'], "Favor de ingresar su telefono.");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Favor de escribir un mensaje.");


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("El correo que escribio no es valido.");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

Este mensaje fue enviado desde su sitio www.mysite.mx:

Nombre: $name
Empresa: $company
Telefono: $telephone
E-mail: $email

Mensaje:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: index2.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en Inglés

Comment: Ya edite el lenguaje, una disculpa por el error, agradeceria la ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: @JeseReyes Tienes que usar la función mail obligatoriamente?? sino prueba usando PHPmailer.

Comment: Previamente funcionaba en mi servidor y ya no funciona, asi que cualquier función que haga llegar los correos estaria genial.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno en vista que puedes usar alguna librería prueba usando [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de como enviar mails usando la autenticacion smtp de gmail a través de esta libreria.

Aunque para usarla con el smtp de gmail tienes que activar previamente el acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras, para esto: ingresa a https://myaccount.google.com/security, una vez ahí ve a **Aplicaciones y sitios conectados** y activa el acceso de **aplicaciones menos seguras**

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Crea una nueva instancia PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Usar SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Habilita el SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//hostname del servidor de correo
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Setea numero del puerto - 587 TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Encryptacion a usar ssl o tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Autenticacion SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username para la autenticación - direccion correo gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
//Password gmail
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//quien envia
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//direccion alternativa
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//quien recibe
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Asunto
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Cuerpo del mensaje
$mail->Body = "Gmail mail test";
//Envia el mensaje, y revisa si existen errores
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mail Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```